# How can I delete a single item from a list in React Native?

Tags: react-native

So that's what my render list looks like:

```
renderEvent(){
return this.props.eventList.map(listedEvent=>
    <CardSection key={listedEvent._id}>

      <EventListItem>
      {listedEvent.eventName}
      </EventListItem>

      <DeleteButton
      onClick={this.deleteEvent(listedEvent._id)}
      key={listedEvent._id}
      />

    </CardSection>
  );
    }
```

and here the rendering of the whole list

```
render(){

if (this.props.eventList !== undefined) {
  return(
        <Card>
          {this.renderEvent()}
        </Card>
        )
}else{
  return(
        <View>
        <Spinner/>
        </View>
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

So far so good, the list and the delete button appear correctly, yet when I try to delete one line, it addresses all. I created my event handler which for now, only logs the passed id.

```
deleteEvent(eventID){
console.log(eventID)
}
```

Yet when called, it logs all the _ids on the list. What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure I'm passing one single id of the list item I'm clicking on?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are rather than passing a `deleteEvent` function to `onClick` prop you are executing it. This causes to deleteEvent fire for each item while rendering.

You can sort this out by changing this,

```
onPress={this.deleteEvent(listedEvent._id)}
```

to this

```
onPress={() => this.deleteEvent(listedEvent._id)}
```

This will also assure that `deleteEvent` is bind with `this`.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to do anything special to call this event handler?

Comment: @TheGabornator Can you explain more _it doesn't work_ part?

Comment: Never mind, I figured out why it didn't call. onClick is for React. It's onPress in React-Native. :) Thanks a lot! You totally saved me!